# Customizer Image-Picker Preview Not Working

Tags: theme-development, images, javascript, theme-customizer, previews

sorry for my English... . 
I am trying to implement an Image Picker in Customizer in order to choose and display a css-background-image on front-page.php. 
Fundamental it works as intended in Frontend... . 
But I cant get the preview in the customizer running. Changed image is only shown after F5 refresh... .

What I've done:
function.php

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('startGalleryImg1', array(
    'default' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/assets/default.jpg',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',

));

$wp_customize->add_control(
   new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
       $wp_customize,
       'startGalleryImg1',
       array(
           'label'      => __( '1st Start Gallery Img', 'theme_name' ),
            'description'      => __( 'Choose first Start Gallery Img', 'theme_name' ),
           'section'    => 'bloook_theme_section',
           'settings'   => 'startGalleryImg1',

       )
   )
)
```

My Template:

```
<a class="item item1" href="#">
            <div class="item-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_theme_mod('startGalleryImg1') ?>')">
            </div>
     <div class="item-content">
        <h3>Demos</h3>
        <p>Web, Video, Musik</p>
     </div>
```

my customizer.js
(which works fine for other fields (textarea... )

```
(function ($) {

wp.customize('startGalleryImg1', function (value) {
    value.bind(function (to) {
        $('.home .item1 .item-bg').css('background-image', 'url( '+ to +')');
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

I wonder if some expert is out there who can help me with this... . Many thanks in advance and kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine for me. I let it here, because someone might need it or have suggestions to do it in a better way. My problem was that the enqueue of js had loaded an old js file... .